# Is it possible in jmeter to record the script for two separate URL Which both URLs are not Integrated.

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

Scenario is like.
I have one Contact page where user will login only, Then after user will access another URL in new tab in the same browser in that URL or tab  user will do the all business functionality.So the my question is, Is it possible in jmeter or if it is possible then how we can do that.

Looking very forward from the jmeter experts.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Suppose I have Page X and Page Y. First I will access the X page URL in the browser then after Login in the application. After again I will open new Tab in the same browser only and will access the Y page URL. Y page URL has all the business functionality. The my Goal is to record the performance script for both the page. But both the page are not integrated. That is the problem. So is there any way to record the script.

Comment: Why is it a problem if the pages are not "integrated"? JMeter captures all HTTP traffic.

Comment: Hi Rage, Actually I was not sure whether Jmeter will record or not because there is no integration b/w both URL. But It is working.